# Laravel Path With Different Views

Tags: laravel

**This is my Route**

```
Route::get('sites/{site_id}/report/{report_id}', array('as'=>'Reports'), 
function($site_id, $report_id){

// $report = ???

return view('reports')->with('report', $report)->with('site_id',$site_id)- 
>with('report_id', $report_id);

});
```

**This is my blade file**

```
<a href="{{route('Reports',['site_id'=>$report->site_id, 
'report_id'=>$report- >report_id])}}">view</a>
```

Here is the problem. I want to make a path for every report. Example is inside this path have a 3 reports **http://localhost:8000/sites/1**

Then when I click one of the report it should give me this path 
**http://localhost:8000/sites/1/report/1** `(sites/$site_id/report/$report_id)`

But it confused me a lot, when you click on report_id = 1 and report_id = 2
The value of the `return view('reports') are still the same how could I make a different views for every reports I have.

You have any thoughts?

Comment: Hello, it would be easier to understand/answer if your explanation had a little better punctuation/grammar/paragraphing. Also, i dont see a for loop in your code ?

Comment: sorry for my bad grammar i'm not used to it i'm trying my best I'm not that good at English.

Comment: No problem, just try shortening your sentences, using periods, and splitting thoughts into paragraphs. You dont need to be good at english to do that.

Comment: @Andrew got edited already.

Comment: Looks like you need to fetch the report or site and then pass it to the blade file? Something like `$report = Report::find($report_id);`?

Comment: Do you have Eloquent models set up for sites an reports?

Comment: @RossWilson yes. `return $this->hasMany('App\Report'); ` Site Model and `return $this->belongsTo('App\Site');` Report Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to get the information from the database. You can use your `App\Report` model to get the information for the report:

```
Route::get('sites/{site_id}/report/{report_id}', ['as' => 'Reports'], function ($site_id, $report_id) {

    $report = App\Report::findOrFail($report_id);

    return view('reports')->with('report', $report)->with('site_id', $site_id)->with('report_id', $report_id);
});
```

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent)

Comment: Its the same dude my site_id and report_id are still null, been tried that before but same output.